# I've used a proxy in my operator[] to implicitly convert a boost::variant. How can I maintain assignment through operator[]?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I'm writing a configuration file parser that reads a configuration file with format `key: value` into an `std::map<string, ConfigVariant` with `ConfigVariant` defined as `typedef boost::variant<double, long int, std::string> ConfigVariant;`

Here are the important parts of my config class:

```
typedef boost::variant<double, long int, std::string> ConfigVariant;

class Config {
private:
  std::map<std::string, ConfigVariant> config_values;

  // This struct is important
  struct Proxy {
  public:
    template<typename T> T as() { return boost::get<T>(data); }
    template<typename T> operator T() { return as<T>(); }

  private:
    ConfigVariant data;

    Proxy(ConfigVariant data) { this->data = data; }
    Proxy(const Proxy &other);
    Proxy & operator=(const Proxy &other);
    friend class Config;
  };

public:
  Config(std::string config_file_name);
  Proxy operator[] (const std::string &key); // Important
};
```

The only relevant implementation is that of `operator[]` which looks like this:

```
Config::Proxy Config::operator[] (const string &key) {
  return Proxy(config_values[key]);
}
```

This code allows me to have something like this:

```
// config_file
double_key: 4.2

// driver.cpp
int main() {
  Config config("path/to/config_file");

  double d = config["double_key"] // Look ma, no cast
  d += 1

  cout << d << endl; // Prints 5.2

  return 0;
}
```

I am happy with this behavior, but as you can see, I cannot return a reference from `operator[]`. Because I am not returning a reference, I cannot perform assignment through `operator[]`. This is somewhat of a problem because I would like to modify the configuration values after loading them from a hash. I would also like to keep the `config["key"]` syntax. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've changing Proxy to store `ConfigVariant *` and then tried overloading `operator=`. Here is exactly what I've tried:

```
Proxy & operator=(ConfigVariant &other) { *data = other; return *this; }
```

This gave me the following error:

```
app/driver.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
app/driver.cpp:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘Config::operator[](const std::string&)(((const std::string&)(& std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"key3"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>()))))))) = 5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125e+0’
app/../config/config.hpp:37: note: candidates are: Config::Proxy& Config::Proxy::operator=(const Config::Proxy&)
app/../config/config.hpp:44: note:                 Config::Proxy& Config::Proxy::operator=(ConfigVariant&)
```

Then I tried:

```
ConfigVariant & operator=(ConfigVariant &other) { *data = other; return *data; }
```

Which gave me pretty much the same error:

```
app/driver.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
app/driver.cpp:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘Config::operator[](const std::string&)(((const std::string&)(& std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"key3"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>()))))))) = 5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125e+0’
app/../config/config.hpp:37: note: candidates are: Config::Proxy& Config::Proxy::operator=(const Config::Proxy&)
app/../config/config.hpp:44: note:                 ConfigVariant& Config::Proxy::operator=(ConfigVariant&)
```

Comment: Overload the assignment operator on your proxy, just as you did for the conversion operator.

Comment: May I suggest Boost PropertyTree, JsonCPP or similar for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This configuration parser is actually just a project I'm doing for fun so using those libraries would defeat the whole purpose ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proxy` currently stores a copy of `ConfigVariant` from the map. Instead, have it store a reference or a pointer to the original object inside the map. Then you can implement `Proxy::operator=` to assign back to that value.

Comment: I've tried both `Proxy & operator=(ConfigVariant &other)` and `ConfigVariant & operator=(ConfigVariant &other)`. See my edit for the errors these have given.

Comment: Have `operator=` take `const ConfigVariant&`. A non-const reference can't bind to a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually "infer the type of the variant". You just made the conversion from variant to target variable's type completely implicit.

I don't recommend this at all, implicit conversions are bad enough without using variant to increase the risk of "doing the wrong thing automatically".

That said, since the conversion works ***only on the assumption*** that the variant contained the *exact type* you're converting to in the first place, you can just as easily return a reference:

```
typedef boost::variant<double, long int, std::string> ConfigVariant;

class Config {
private:
  std::map<std::string, ConfigVariant> config_values;

  // This struct is important
  struct Proxy {
  public:
    template<typename T> T& as() { return boost::get<T>(data); }
    template<typename T> operator T&() { return as<T>(); }

  private:
    ConfigVariant& data;

    Proxy(ConfigVariant& data) { this->data = data; }
    Proxy(const Proxy &other);
    Proxy & operator=(const Proxy &other);
    friend class Config;
  };

public:
  Config(std::string config_file_name);
  Proxy operator[] (const std::string &key); // Important
};
```

Now you should be able to:

```
// driver.cpp
Config config("path/to/config_file");

double& d = config["double_key"] // Look ma, no cast
d += 1;                          // edits the Config instance
```

Comment: Of course the implicit conversion is dangerous, but at least you can use `app_config[key].as<type>()` to be explicit. As for your solution, it is interesting but I couldn't get it to compile. Also, I am looking to something like `app_config[key] = new_value` which is what currently doesn't work.